# sonar-server-5.6.1: BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO properties (prop_key, resource_id, user_id, text_value)

Tags: sonarqube

My sonarqube 5.6.1 server failed to start after a system reboot. It is possible that there were plugin updates that were pending a sonarqube server restart. Any advice on what to do?

The stack trace is:

```
2018.01.09 13:02:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarXML / 1.4.3.1027 / 39588245cecf538bb27be4e496ff303b0143d20b
2018.01.09 13:02:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Web / 2.5.0.476 / 636872f5d37fa7a440fe07d08d504e1a881225e5
2018.01.09 13:02:21 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
2018.01.09 13:02:21 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutorException: org.sonar.db.property.PropertiesMapper.insert (batch index #2) failed. 1 prior sub executor(s) completed successfully, but will be rolled back. Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO properties (prop_key, resource_id, user_id, text_value)
    VALUES ('sonar.core.id', NULL, NULL, '20180109130149') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:127) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:114) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.flushStatements(BaseExecutor.java:109) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.commit(BaseExecutor.java:201) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.commit(CachingExecutor.java:104) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:174) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.commit(DefaultSqlSession.java:169) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        at org.sonar.db.DbSession.commit(DbSession.java:41) ~[sonar-db-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.db.BatchSession.commit(BatchSession.java:168) ~[sonar-db-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.db.property.PropertiesDao.insertGlobalProperties(PropertiesDao.java:268) ~[sonar-db-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PersistentSettings.saveProperties(PersistentSettings.java:92) ~[sonar-server-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.startup.ServerMetadataPersister.start(ServerMetadataPersister.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320) ~[sonar-core-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141) ~[sonar-core-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:216) ~[sonar-server-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:189) ~[sonar-server-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:113) ~[sonar-server-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO properties (prop_key, resource_id, user_id, text_value)
    VALUES ('sonar.core.id', NULL, NULL, '20180109130149') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2743) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1928) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:405) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2892) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doFlushStatements(BatchExecutor.java:103) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the new plugin?

Comment: I do not know which plugin is the issue if any. The last message in my log was "Deploying Ruby on Rails applications" which does not seem to be plugin related AFAICT.

Comment: According to the log the Web plugin could be the cause. Update your question with information which steps you performed before getting this error. Use a database backup is also an option. Plan to update to version 6.

Comment: I don't know what changed my server was rebooted and then I saw this sonarqube startup issue. I have manually removed all plugin from /opt/sonarqube-5.6.1/extensions/plugins, restarted server and I still see the startup error. I need to recover from this errror before I can plan an upgrade to version 6.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixed my startup issue by deleting all plugins and restoring the original plugins from backup. Moral of the story is to make sure to have a backup of your plugins before updating.